# Find the core word of a long name entity

Tags: nlp

everyone.

Here is the problem and its background. I collect a lot of name entity from the web.There are many long terms.so i wish to find the common saying of the name entity (or the core word).

For example,

i have the word Los Angeles, and i want to get LA.

or a very formal place name, and i want to get the short name for it.

There're a lot of OOV , so it's impossible to look up a dictionary.

How can i solve the problem？ Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: He wants an acronym generator, I think. What have you tried, and what language(s) are you using?

Comment: @arxanas it's Chinese.I wanna the algorithm framework doesn't relate to the language.Maybe i can use the Web resource,query log？

Comment: @KenstonChoi already updated the question.

Comment: @David I don't see what being Chinese has to do with it; I can't find any examples in the new version of the question.

Comment: @arxanas For example,THU is short for Tsinghua University (清华大学)

Answer (score 0):

If the cases are like THU = Tsinghua University, and we want it to be as accurate as possible, then I think we need to rely on existing knowledge sources as no algorithm may guess all cases correctly, given the many different possibilities/alternatives for a given named-entity (e.g., TU).

You can try sources like:
http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com, or even mine from Wikipedia, looking for parentheses.

If you don't need 100% precision, then you can base it from the initials like Los Angeles - LA, relying on the characters' cases. For Tsinghua University, I believe that you need to refer to the Chinese characters as guide: 清 - Tsing 华 - Hua 大学 - University -> THU.

But initials are not always the basis for all cases. For example, `American Online = AOL` rather than just `AO`. You can do some validation perhaps using Google search, with the query `"American Online (AO)"` (include the quotations, since texts introducing acronyms are usually written that way), only to find no matching links, but using the query `"American Online (AOL)"` results to several exact matches.